# jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 + Photoswipe Associates All The Links With Itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have implemented Photoswipe with jQuery Mobile 1.4.2. The gallery works perfecty but after viewing the gallery all the navigation links, etc. are being associated with photoswipe and link to blank photoswipe images so you cannot leave the page.

Live demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/flymen8888/JFW7S/6/**

```
$("#gallery a").photoSwipe(
{
    jQueryMobile: true,
    loop: false,
    enableMouseWheel: false,
    enableKeyboard: false
});
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$("#gallery a").photoSwipe` to `$("#gallery .gallery-item a").photoSwipe`.